# I want get the numbers of records with a criteria from a bd access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Hi I just need to include the criteria = *RS* somewhere in the field SEG_OPE_REMARQ from the AQ_SEG table in ACCESS

I just need to get the RS part

Everything in the rest of the code work fine

```
Sub GetNumbersSigeqR()

        'Get Retrait SIGEQ de AQ_SEG_EPEL_XX.mdb.mdb


    Dim mrc As String
    Dim retrait As String

    mrc = Val(Range("D2").Value)

    If Len(mrc) < 2 Then

        mrc = "0" + mrc

    End If


    retrait = "AQ_SEG_EPEL_" + mrc + ".mdb"

    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")


    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & folderPath & "\" & retrait
    strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM AQ_SEG ;"
    cn.Open strConnection
    Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
    Sheets("T9Cp1").Range("G97").Value = rs.Fields(0)
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to only count the rows that match a certain criteria?

Comment: Yes the criteria is contain RS in the field. I want to get the count of records that contains th value *RS* whatever what string is before or after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure I understand the question *(as you mention field containing RS but you also have an object called RS)* but based on your response and the original question, the following query for `strSQL` would count only the rows where the field contains '`RS`':

```
strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM AQ_SEG WHERE SEG_OPE_REMARQ LIKE '%RS%';"
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. Sorry if I wasn't clear it's not my first language!

Comment: No problem. It was a SQL question really but we got there anyway. Best of luck.